# Dynamic interpolation

Tags: excel, interpolation

I have the following matrix, please relate to the Date an Value columns:

```
Date                   Value    Date Diff  Hours Diff
    29/12/2014 8:00     24.940      
    29/12/2014 9:00     24.960  0.04          1
    29/12/2014 10:00                          1
    29/12/2014 11:00    25.020  0.08          1
    29/12/2014 12:00                          1
    29/12/2014 13:00                          1
    29/12/2014 14:00                          1
    29/12/2014 15:00    25.070                1
```

As can be seen there are missing values sometime of one line sometimes more than one line (the number of missing lines is dynamic). I would like to make an interpolation and to calculate the missing values by using linear interpolation. (The matrix might contain large number of lines).

The final result should be as followed:

```
Date                   Value    Date Diff  Hours Diff
    29/12/2014 8:00     24.940      
    29/12/2014 9:00     24.960  0.04          1
    29/12/2014 10:00    24.99                 1
    29/12/2014 11:00    25.020  0.08          1
    29/12/2014 12:00    25.0325               1
    29/12/2014 13:00    25.045                1
    29/12/2014 14:00    25.0575               1
    29/12/2014 15:00    25.070                1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best method would be a [Range.DataSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839262.aspx) method with a computed **Step** parameter.

```
Sub seriesFill()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet11")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2)
            Do While CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Columns(2)))
                With .Range(rng, rng.End(xlUp))
                    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, _
                                Step:=(.Cells(.Cells.Count).Value2 - .Cells(1).Value2) / (.Rows.Count - 1)
                End With
                Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Your results should be similar to the following. This can be manually applied with the Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series command but a large number of repetitions makes a sub procedure the more viable method.

[image: dataSeries_Fill]